# Moq Extended Setup With Single shared Return

Tags: c#, .net, moq

What I want to do is to define one or more `Setup`(s) to one `Return` call on multiple method calls of the mocked object; hence avoiding multiple single calls to do `Setup().Return()`s.

The compiler provides an error when attempting the following which demonstrates the goal, so this is not an appropriate way to achieve that goal.

```
var mPlatform = new Mock<IPlatformCommunicator>();

mPlatform.Setup(mp => mp.PreStart(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()))
         .Setup(mp => mp.Start(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()))
         ...
         .Returns(mockStatusIndeterminate.Object as IStatus);
```

Is there way to define multiple method calls in `Setup` to economize the total lines of code?

---

This is not an option too:

```
.Setup(mp => mp.PreStart(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()) || mp.Start(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()))
```

Comment: The demonstrated goals are not how that framework is designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Nkosi mentions, not really. But there are options that may work depending on your usage.

1. `SetReturnsDefault`

```cs
void Main()
{
    var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    fooMock.SetReturnsDefault<string>("This is a mocked value");
    var foo = fooMock.Object;

    Console.WriteLine($"foo.Bar(): {foo.Bar()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"foo.Baz(): {foo.Baz()}");
}

public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar();
    string Baz();
}
```

Any method that returns a string will return whatever you specify.

2. The default value provider is similar but across the board.

```
void Main()
{
    var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    fooMock.DefaultValueProvider = new MyDefaultValueProvider();
    var foo = fooMock.Object;

    Console.WriteLine($"foo.Bar(): {foo.Bar()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"foo.Baz(): {foo.Baz()}");
}

public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar();
    string Baz();
}

public class MyDefaultValueProvider : DefaultValueProvider
{
    protected override object GetDefaultValue(Type type, Mock mock)
    {
        return "This is my default value";
    }
}
```

3. Create your own extension; the following is a working mvp

```
void Main()
{
    var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    fooMock.Setup(new Expression<Func<IFoo, string>>[] { x => x.Bar(), x => x.Baz() }, "This is a mocked value");
    var foo = fooMock.Object;

    Console.WriteLine($"foo.Bar(): {foo.Bar()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"foo.Baz(): {foo.Baz()}");
}

public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar();
    string Baz();
}

public static class MoqExtensions
{
    public static Mock<T> Setup<T, U>(this Mock<T> self, Expression<Func<T, U>>[] setups, U returns)
        where T : class
    {
        foreach (var setup in setups)
        {
            self.Setup(setup).Returns(returns);
        }

        return self;
    }
}
```

All of the above produce the following result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time on the answer and I appreciate it. I will contrast this with the other answer to see which is more robust. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own extension method on `Mock<T>` that does what you want:

```cs
public static class MoqExt {
    public static void SetupReturnOnAll<T, TResult>(
        this Mock<T> mock,
        TResult returnValue,
        params Expression<Func<T, TResult>>[] expressions)
        where T: class {
            foreach (var expr in expressions)
                mock.Setup(expr).Returns(returnValue);
        }
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```cs
mPlatform
    .SetupReturnOnAll(
        mockStatusIndeterminate.Object as IStatus,
        mp => mp.PreStart(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()),
        mp => mp.Start(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()));
```

---

With some extra effort to could improve the interface to this:

```cs
mPlatform
    .SetupAll(
        mp => mp.PreStart(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()),
        mp => mp.Start(It.IsAny<Action<IStatus>>()))
    .Return(mockStatusIndeterminate.Object as IStatus);
```

For that you'll need an extra class though:

```cs
public class MultiSetup<T, TResult>
    where T: class {
    public Mock<T> Mock { get; }
    public Expression<Func<T, TResult>>[] Expressions { get; }
    
    public MultiSetup(Mock<T> mock, Expression<Func<T, TResult>>[] expressions)
        => (Mock, Expressions) = (mock, expressions);
    
    public void Return(TResult returnValue) {
        foreach (var expr in Expressions)
            Mock.Setup(expr).Returns(returnValue);
    }
}
```

And you'd create it with this extension:

```cs
public static class MoqExt {
    public static MultiSetup<T, TResult> SetupAll<T, TResult>(
        this Mock<T> mock,
        params Expression<Func<T, TResult>>[] expressions)
        where T : class
        => new MultiSetup<T, TResult>(mock, expressions);
}
```

Comment: Ausgezeichnet! This appears to handle my needs. I will test it against the other answer to see which is more robust. Thanks.